# how do I find length of largest subarray with sum of all elements in subarray is 0 using C i don't know where the mistake is.. please anyone tell me

Tags: arrays, c, recursion

c program to find largest subarray with sum 0

I am unable to understand why my code is not running properly
it is keep on asking me input
please any one try to fix my code....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void popout(int a[100], int q, int n, int j) {
  int z;
  z = n;
  for (int o = q; o < n - 1; o++) {
    a[o] = a[o + 1]; // deletes one number
  }
  int g = j;
  if (g != 1) {
    z--; /*function calls recursively till we are deleting only one number*/
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      popout(a, a[i], z, g - 1); /* after deleting one number again
                                 again runs a loop to delete other
                                 number from already deleted array*/
    }
    g--;
  }
}

int main() {
  int n;
  int f;
  int a[100];
  int b[100];
  printf("enter number of elemnts");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("enter elements");
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    b[i] = a[i];
  for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
    a[0] = a[0] + a[j];
  if (a[0] == 0)
    printf("%d", n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    a[i] = b[i];
  /* pop out number by number */
  for (int p = 1; p < n; p++) { // p:number of elements to be deleted at onece
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      popout(a, a[i], n, p);
      for (int g = 1; g < n - 1; g++) {
        a[0] += a[g];
      }
      if (a[0] == 0) {
        printf("%d", n - p);
        exit;
      } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          a[i] = b[i];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular algorithm you are trying to implement?

Comment: And the comment at the top says that it keeps asking for input. Is your issue with reading in data from the command line, or with the algorithm to find a particular subarray?

Comment: "not running properly" is not a useful problem description. Please be more specific. Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result. Also, have you actually done any debugging of the problem? Run your program in a debugger and step thru it line by line.

Comment: "it is keep on asking me input" since you write `printf("enter elements"); for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf("%d", &a[i]);`? You have to provide more context about your problem, or I don't think this is your code.

Comment: @Rainning what i am trying to say is it has to read only n elements right? but instead it is reading infinite elements in array.....

Comment: @kaylum it is not reading elements into array properly is what I am saying... like in first line it has to read number of elements in array then it has to read that many number of elements into array but it is reading infinite numbers and it is still going..... it is not stopping to read. Example am giving 8 as first input(i.e. number of elements) then after entering 8 elements(1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,4,5) it is not stopping and asking for inputs again

Comment: https://ideone.com/iKoXBb, I provide input `10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` it successfully return `Success #stdin #stdout 0.14s 5540KB`.If it indeed read infinitely many `int` the result should be `TLE`. I think you should put `{ }` for each for-loop, even if they have only one line in it, and take care about your indentation.

Comment: @Rainning but still I am unable to find any error in my logic can you please tell me where my program is getting wrong..... It is either reading infinite values or it is just exiting the program without doing anything...

Comment: The best way to solve this is to insert breakpoint(s) in your IDE(i.e. the one you edit your code) and run it in debug mode, to see what's really going on at each break point. In your case you only have to insert the breakpoint on the `scanf()` and the `for` above it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a variant of the *maximum subarray problem* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem). A more efficient solution to solve this uses a *hash map*

A C implementation is in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-largest-subarray-with-0-sum/ and https://tutorialspoint.dev/data-structure/hashing-data-structure/find-the-largest-subarray-with-0-sum

Comment: I guess OP is more interested to know why their code is not working. Moreover, if I am not wrong, the links you propose concern C++ code, not C code.